# Unable to stop activity in android

Tags: android, crash

I am working on `android studio`. While my device is in `Portrait` mode it works perfect, but when i rotate my screen to `landscape` mode then the app crashes while giving below error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.accurat.myapp/com.example.accurat.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.disconnect()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3845)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3899)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4103)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.disconnect()' on a null object reference
at com.example.accurat.myapp.MainActivity.onStop(MainActivity.java:249)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1301)
at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6414)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3840)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3899) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4103) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

and it hits at the below code part

```
 protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect(); // it hit here

}
```

The below method is called while getting the coordinates.

```
 protected synchronized  void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    if(mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this this might help you!!

Keep this in the manifest file

```
<activity name= ".YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: You can't use the landscape mode then

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
   protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect(); // it hit here

}
```

to this

```
  protected void onStop() {
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect(); // it hit here
super.onStop();


}
```

Comment: Still same issue , again hitting at ` mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();`

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            // do nothing, just override
}


IN LAyout

<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `super.onStop()` as last thing in your `onStop()` implementation:

```
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: still having same issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something with onConfigurationChange method?

Do this if you want to avoid the landscape mode:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

**From the documentation**

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

> Advertencia: A partir de Android 3.2 (el nivel de API 13), el “tamaño
>   de pantalla” también cambia cuando el dispositivo cambia entre la
>   orientación vertical y horizontal. Por lo tanto, si deseas evitar los
>   reinicios en tiempo de ejecución debido al cambio de orientación
>   cuando desarrollas para el nivel de API 13 o niveles superiores (según
>   se declara en los atributos minSdkVersion y targetSdkVersion ), debes
>   incluir el valor "screenSize" además del valor "orientation". Es
>   decir, debes declarar android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize".
>   Sin embargo, si tu aplicación tiene como destino el nivel de API 12 o
>   niveles superiores, tu actividad siempre maneja este cambio de
>   configuración por sí misma (este cambio de configuración no reinicia
>   tu actividad, ni siquiera cuando se ejecuta en un dispositivo Android
>   3.2 o superior).

Normal use:

Build the Google api object in onCreate()

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //...
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

Connect on onStart()

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}
```

And disconnect like this

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: can't do this as i have to get coordinates and on button click the api is called. If i move out the in `onCreate` method it will automatically get `lat` and `long` and this i don't want

Comment: And if you starts the app and go back without clicking the button the crash doesn't happen? It seems the code will try to disconnect the mGoogleApiClient and this has not been initialized

Comment: Yes it does crash but i can't simply put the code out of the button click